Google Promotional Annotation doesn't work in emails sent by SalesForce Marketing Cloud
I'm trying to use the notes feature in Gmails but I'm not having success. Communications are sent via the Salesforce Marketing Cloud platform and I am following documentation at the this link:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_google_promotions_tab.htm&type=5
And also in this :
https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview?hl=pt-br#deal-annotation
Only the feature of appearing an image does not work. I would like support from the Google team.
I tried using Microdata and JSON-SD but both don't show the promotional image, I managed to make only the other Google Annotations features work

I've run into the same issue. Some articles suggest that domains need to be whitelisted by Google for that to work. However, I've not had any luck getting any response from the email in the documentation. Others have tried using Google's issue tracker but haven't seen any evidence that it worked.
To use the following email annotation features, send an email to p-Promo-Outreach@google.com. Source: https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview).
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/331926165
